# LinkedIn follow button results in about:blank page

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

After I added the LinkedIn Company Page follow button to our website, clicking the button results in an about:blank page. Apparently, after reading some topics concerning the same problem, the Company page does get followed. However, it doesn't look very professional getting redirected to some blank page. Making this post, hoping there is a workaround now that hasn't been posted to the other topics or to get a response from a LinkedIn employee.

**Issue details:**
Chrome 67, IE11, Edge 42 and Brave 0.23 give the about:blank page.

Firefox is currently the only browser working and it redirects me to the 'confirm follow' page, giving me the message: 'Congratulations! You're now following ...'

So anyone knows a fix or (if working for LinkedIn) any estimate on when the issue will be solved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works in IE11 for me. But still issue persists in Chrome. Any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

this is definitely a third party bug on linkedin's side. This problem has been going on for almost a year now and there has never been a good solution that I could find. the best thing to do might be to just delete it from your page. In the link below you will find the source I am talking about.

Hopefully, this will give you a bit more information.

[Wix message 23-January-2018](https://support.wix.com/en/article/january-23-2018-linkedin-follow-app-redirects-to-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can contact LinkedIn, you should look for workarounds that enhance the customer experience, like putting some helper text that explains what will happen after the button is pushed.

Also, for what it's worth, if you have some level of premium support with Microsoft, you could try to escalate and have it routed across the org chart. (That's a purely theoretical, I have no recent experience with Microsoft support at any premium level).